# When DECRYPTING: padding is invalid and cannot be removed if nothing read

Tags: c#, encryption, stream

It seems that [THIS question is related,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583112/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed)  but it's not.
In my case the exception "padding is invalid and cannot be removed" occurs when **decrypting**, in the related question is it when **encrypting**

The first question people ask is: what have you tried? I've tried a lot. So even after removing all superfluous text, my description is quite long. Sorry for that.

> My conclusion is that the exception 'padding is invalid and cannot be removed' is thrown within `CryptoSteam.FlushFinalBlock`, which is called by `CryptoStream.Dispose()`.  This happens if nothing has been read from the Stream.

[Reference source CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptostream.cs)

If I read all data or at least one byte during the decryption process everything works fine.

If I read nothing, I get a CryptoGraphicException. **Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.**

I tried the following:

- Below a complete encrypt / decrypt cycle. Works fine, no exception, no need to change default padding, no FlushFinalBlock needed. The read data equals the original data
- If I only read one byte: no exception either, no need to change default padding, no FlushFinalBlock needed. A proper Dispose() takes care of this
- If I don't read anything I get the mentioned exception
- An extra FlushFinalBlock before Dispose does not help

The code below shows a complete correctly working encrypt / decrypt Test procedure. The decrypted bytes equal the original bytes:

**Data:**

```
byte[] key;
byte[] iv;
byte[] testData = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
byte[] encryptedData;
byte[] decryptedData;
```

**Encryption of the data:**

```
using (Stream testStream = new MemoryStream(testData))
{
    using (RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
    {   // Generate and remember keys:
        rijndael.GenerateKey();
        rijndael.GenerateIV();
        key = rijndael.Key;
        iv = rijndael.IV;

        using (var encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(testStream, encryptor,
                   CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {   // read all bytes from the cryptoStream and put in a EncryptedData
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(cryptoStream))
                {
                    encryptedData = reader.ReadBytes(10000);
                    // expect no bytes anymore
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All TestBytes are encrypted in encryptedData. key and iv are known

**Decrypt the data**

```
using (Stream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedData))
{
    using (var rijnDael = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijnDael.Key = key;
        rijnDael.IV = iv;
        using (var decryptor = rijnDael.CreateDecryptor())
        {
            using (Stream decryptedStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, decryptor,
                   CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(decryptedStream))
                {
                    decryptedData = reader.ReadBytes(1000);
                    // expect no bytes anymore
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Check that the decrypted data equals the original data:
Debug.Assert(testData.SequenceEqual(decryptedData));
```

This works fine. If I read only one decrypted byte, there is no exception:

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(decryptedStream))
{
    byte b = reader.ReadByte();
}
```

However, If I read nothing the exception occurs:

```
using (Stream decryptedStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, decryptor,
       CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(decryptedStream))
    {
    } // exception during Dispose()
}
```

One of the answers in the related question mentioned at the beginning included a FlushFinalBlock. This does not help, as expected, because the CrypteStream.Dispose already calls this

```
using (Stream decryptedStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, decryptor,
       CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(decryptedStream))
    {
        if (!decryptedStream.HasFlushedFinalBlock)
        { 
            decryptedStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            // even though it hasn't flushed the final bloc
            // I get the same Exception during Flush
         }
    } 
}
```

So now we know that the Exception occurs because of `CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock`, which is also done in the `CryptoStream.Dispose()`

The problem has nothing to do with the binary reader. If I read directly one byte then there is no exception, without reading anything I get the exception during the Dispose of the CryptoStream

```
using (Stream decryptedStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, decryptor,
       CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    int b = decryptedStream.ReadByte();
} // exception during Dispose()
```

So what should I do to prevent the exception? Read one dummy byte? Seems a bit silly, isn't it?

Comment: In the linked question "when I try to **decrypt**, I get the following exception:" (My emphasis). So what makes you think the linked question is about encryption? Also, if you'll read up a little on encryption and padding, you'll realise that it doesn't make *sense* to get such an error during encryption.

Comment: oops.my fault. Repaired