# compile failure in VS community 2019 when building a windows app (x64) developed by others

Tags: c#, wpf

Hey When I tried to build a window app from the source-code that my friend made. 
The build failed and the following error came up:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:'
Padding is invalid and cannot be removed'
```

The app is made my friend in his VS community 2019, it compiled without any issue. The app was successfully compile when my friend tried to build it in his VS professional 2019(in a different account).I have checked the source-code and I couldn't find any problem with it.

The app is a (x64)only app and it is a wpf project. Just wondering if anyone knows if there is any dependency in VS community which prevents me from compiling the apps?

Comment: What, exactly, displays that error?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answer will shed some light for you:
[Padding is invalid and cannot be removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583112/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed).

I would also suggest right clicking on your solution and "Cleaning solution" then "Rebuild Solution". Or even better, delete your .vs Folder, as well as your bin and obj folders.