# AES Padding is Invalid And Cannot Be Removed

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I am using AES criptography algorithms to encrypt and decrypt my values in my project. My code works almost everytime but sometimes I get `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed` error. My project is ASP .NET Core 3.1 project and it's published on IIS Server 8.5.

As said at [Padding is invalid and cannot be removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583112/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed) question asked 9 years ago, my keys and salts are always set 128 bits and padding mode is always set to PKCS#7 like this code: `aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;`.

But sometimes, I got this error. After debugging my code with the **same** key, salt and decrypted value I didn't get any error and my code works fine for another 10 hours or so. I have no idea why my code behaves like this but I couldn't find any solution.

My Constructor:

```
public void KriptoAlgoritmasiniAyarla(string password, string salt, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm)
{
    if (password == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));
    if (salt == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(salt));

    DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt));

    var rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
    var rgbIv = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);

    _sifreleyici = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, rgbIv);
    _desifreleyici = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(rgbKey, rgbIv);
}
```

My encrption code:

```
public byte[] ByteDizisineSifrele(string plainText)
{
    try
    {

        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create a new AesManaged.    
        using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            // Create MemoryStream    
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Create crypto stream using the CryptoStream class. This class is the key to encryption    
                // and encrypts and decrypts data from any given stream. In this case, we will pass a memory stream    
                // to encrypt    
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, _sifreleyici, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    // Create StreamWriter and write data to a stream    
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                        sw.Write(plainText);
                    encrypted = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        // Return encrypted data    
        return encrypted;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw exp;
    }
}
```

My decryption code:

```
public string ByteDizisiDesifreEt(byte[] cipherText)
{
    try
    {
        string plaintext = null;
        // Create AesManaged    
        using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            // Create the streams used for decryption.    
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                // Create crypto stream    
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, _desifreleyici, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    // Read crypto stream    
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cs))
                        plaintext = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return plaintext;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw exp;
    }
}
```

Comment: While sending the data over the network encode in base64 or similar. Binary data can make problems.

Comment: You're reading from the `MemoryStream` before closing the `CryptoStream`; the last block may not have been flushed. Move your `encrypted = ms.ToArray();` out of the using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because you are reusing the same [`ICryptoTransform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform?view=netframework-4.7.2) objects (`_sifreleyici` and `_desifreleyici`). At some point, the transform object can't be reused anymore and therefore the interface has a property to determine that. The [`ICryptoTransform.CanReuseTransform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform.canreusetransform?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_ICryptoTransform_CanReuseTransform) property.

Consequently, you need to check this property and recreate the objects when you get `false`.

**Example**

```cs
private readonly byte[] Key, IV;

public void KriptoAlgoritmasiniAyarla(
    string password, 
    string salt,
    SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm)
{
    // ...

    Key = // Get the key..
    IV =  // Get the IV..
}

private ICryptoTransform encryptor;
private ICryptoTransform Encryptor
{
    get
    {
        if (encryptor == null || !encryptor.CanReuseTransform)
        {
            encryptor?.Dispose();
            encryptor = Algorithm.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV);
        }
        return encryptor;
    }
}

private ICryptoTransform decryptor;
private ICryptoTransform Decryptor
{
    get
    {
        if (decryptor == null || !decryptor.CanReuseTransform)
        {
            decryptor?.Dispose();
            decryptor = Algorithm.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV);
        }
        return decryptor;
    }
}
```

Then use these two properties in the related methods to create the `CryptoStream`.

---

**Alternative**

I'd like to propose the code below as an alternative that can be used with the classes that derive from the [`SymmetricAlgorithm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm?view=net-5.0) abstract class.

```cs
public class SymmetricCrypto<T> : IDisposable where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{
    private readonly T Algorithm = new T();

    public SymmetricCrypto()
    {
        Algorithm.GenerateKey();
        Algorithm.GenerateIV();
    }

    public SymmetricCrypto(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        Algorithm.Key = key;
        Algorithm.IV = iv;
    }

    public SymmetricCrypto(string pass)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass);
        var rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pass, 
            new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(bytes), 1000);

        Algorithm.Key = rfc.GetBytes(Algorithm.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize / 8);
        Algorithm.IV = rfc.GetBytes(Algorithm.LegalBlockSizes[0].MinSize / 8);
    }

    public SymmetricCrypto(byte[] pass)
    {
        var rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pass, 
            new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(pass), 1000);

        Algorithm.Key = rfc.GetBytes(Algorithm.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize / 8);
        Algorithm.IV = rfc.GetBytes(Algorithm.LegalBlockSizes[0].MinSize / 8);
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(string input) =>
        Transform(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input), Algorithm.CreateEncryptor());

    public string Decrypt(byte[] input) =>
        Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Transform(input, Algorithm.CreateDecryptor()));

    private byte[] Transform(byte[] input, ICryptoTransform cryptoTrans)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoTrans, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() => Algorithm.Dispose();
}
```

Usage:

```cs
void SomeCaller()
{
    using (var crypt = new SymmetricCrypto<AesManaged>("password"))
    {
        var bytes = crypt.Encrypt("Plain Text....");
        // ...

        var plainText = crypt.Decrypt(bytes);
        // ...
    }
}
```