# Why are my Powershell Secrets Cmdlets now throwing exceptions

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, secret-manager

If I run any of the secrets vault cmdlets I get the following error:

> Get-SecretInfo: Exception calling "GetInstance" with "0" argument(s):
> "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."

Another example:

```
> get-secret -Vault Secrets -Name SecretName  -AsPlainText
```

> Get-Secret: Exception calling "GetInstance" with "0" argument(s):
> "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." Get-Secret: Exception
> calling "GetInstance" with "0" argument(s): "Padding is invalid and
> cannot be removed." Get-Secret: The secret SecretName was not found.

I'm using the latest version of `Powershell`.

Has anyone encountered this before and now how to fix it or workaround it?

Comment: When you say _now_ - has something changed in your environment? By _PowerShell_, do you mean Windows PowerShell or [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)? Perhaps the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8583112/45375) provide pointers.

Comment: @mklement0 yes I’m using pwsh via Windows Terminal. I’ve had secret store and secret management installed for 2 years and it was working fine last time I used it on Thursday

Comment: So it is PowerShell (Core) v7.4.1? Note that by using code styling (`PowerShell`), you're suggesting the name of an _executable_, and `powershell[.exe]` is the executable of Windows PowerShell. There's a dedicated tag for PowerShell  7+, which I've now added to the question. Not that I'm too hopeful that it'll make a difference, but you can try updating the underlying modules: `Update-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement, Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore`

Comment: Only change I’ve made to the machine in last day is to install Power Automate Desktop

Comment: @mklement0 I assume if I uninstall and then reinstall then I’ll lose the current secrets? Or can I safely uninstall/reinstall the management module?

Comment: I just tried, and it does seem to _retain_ the secrets; not sure where they are stored and how to actually remove them - I encourage you to research the storage location and make a backup first, though.

Comment: @mklement0 I reinstalled both modules but the error is still the same. Not sure what to try next to get into my vault. We use One drive and PS-Core's modules are stored on it .... was thinking that might be connected - not too sure what to try next

Comment: That _may_ indeed be related to your problem: The original encryption _may_ be specific not just to your user account, but to the specific _combination_ of user account _and machine_ - the latter applies to the DPAPI, but I'm not sure if it is used in this case. If that is the case then you'll only be able to decrypt any given secret _on the machine where it was created_.